# How to implement seiyria-bootstrap-slider

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-slider

I am getting 2 identical slider bars overlapping. I only want 1 slider bar.

Not sure how to implement this plugin. Has anyone used it successfully?

**Web Document Snippet:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- seiyria-bootstrap-slider Plugin -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
...

<style> /* 2017-02-21 override to fix styling issues with plugin */
  div#fixBootstrapSliderPluginStyles div.slider.slider-horizontal { margin-bottom: 20px !important; }
  div#fixBootstrapSliderPluginStyles div.slider.slider-horizontal div.slider-tick-label-container { margin-left: -52.5px !important; }
  div#fixBootstrapSliderPluginStyles div.slider.slider-horizontal div.slider-tick-label-container div.slider-tick-label { width: 105px !important; }
</style>

<script> // https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider
  var values = ['None', 'Read', 'Speak'];
  var formatter = (index) => values[index];
</script>

<!-- Slider (default "English") -->
<div class="form-group" id="fixBootstrapSliderPluginStyles">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="language_english">English</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="language_english" type="text" data-provide="slider"
      data-slider-ticks="[0, 1, 2]"
      data-slider-ticks-labels='["None", "Read", "Speak"]'
      data-slider-min="0"
      data-slider-max="2"
      data-slider-step="1"
      data-slider-value="2"
      data-slider-tooltip="show"
    />
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  new Slider( '#language_english', {formatter} );
</script>

...
</body>
</html>
```

**Here's what it looks like in Chrome (latest) and IE (latest):**
[image]

**My jsFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/kretrjgz/

Comment: not sure what you're asking but youre creating two sliders .. comment the bottom script tag content ... ? https://jsfiddle.net/kretrjgz/1/

Comment: I am still struggling to understand your question - i answered it in comments, you are creating two instances of the bar. if you remove the bottom script tag it should work fine (new Slider...) you created one in HTML (on document.ready it gets shadow'd to a slider) then created ANOTHER ONE in script tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two instances of the slider.

if you remove the bottom script tag it should work fine

```
<script>
  //new Slider( '#language_english', {formatter} );
</script>
```

you created one in HTML and one on the script tag (without destroying the prior).

if you place a script tag at the bottom with something like 5 times new slider

```
 new Slider( '#language_english', {formatter} );
 new Slider( '#language_english', {formatter} );
 new Slider( '#language_english', {formatter} );
 new Slider( '#language_english', {formatter} );
 new Slider( '#language_english', {formatter} );
```

it will create 5 sliders. as expected.

the documentation is really easy-peasy to follow with examples and fireworks and all:

https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider

Answer (score 0):

Remove `data-provider="slider"` from the markup: https://jsfiddle.net/kretrjgz/2

`data-provide` automatically instantiates a slider with your options. You cannot provide a function this way, so the only way to do this is to provide it in JS. Generally you will either put all your options in one place or the other, not both, which is what makes this case particularly confusing.

You can see that `data-provide` is well documented (see [example #19](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/)).

Comment: @H.Ferrence Actually, it's not even broken in IE11. It's because this JSfiddle uses ES6 syntax, which IE11 does not appear to support. If you need backwards compatibility, consider not using ES6.

Comment: @H.Ferrence ... because it uses ES6. Either transpile it or downgrade it to ES5.

Comment: @H.Ferrence In specific, it uses [arrow functions](http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies) and [shorthand properties](http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand). You will need to convert the code that uses those features to their ES5 equivalent (which is what IE11 will support).